# Importing .JSON into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, mysql-workbench

I have a very large (200k+ lines) and sort of complex .JSON file I need to store in MySQL so that I can query it.

This .JSON is broken up into two main parts, "edges" and "nodes", shown below is an example of both:

```
{
    "edges": [
        {
            "source": "279364692",
            "target": "282656527",
            "id": "2959",
            "attributes": {
                "Weight": "1.0"
            },
            "color": "rgb(184,178,213)",
            "size": 1.0
        },
        {
            "source": "279364426",
            "target": "3088727691",
            "id": "2122",
            "attributes": {
                "Weight": "1.0"
            },
            "color": "rgb(182,131,187)",
            "size": 1.0
        },
    ],

"nodes": [
    {
        "x": -1281.15625,
        "y": 173.54820251464844,
        "id": "2705660357",
        "attributes": {},
        "color": "rgb(237,248,251)",
        "size": 10.0
    },
    {
        "x": -269.597900390625,
        "y": 1419.9178466796875,
        "id": "3341801730",
        "attributes": {},
        "color": "rgb(237,248,251)",
        "size": 10.0
    }
]
}
```

My entire .JSON file is exactly the same format as this, everything is under "edges" and "nodes". There are several tutorials on how to import .JSON files, and I have tried most of them. But I haven't found anything that can handle data like mine.

So, how can I store this information in a MySQL database?

Comment: What *specific* error are you getting? What is your *specific* schema?

Comment: I've ran into several errors with several different implementations, I left out the specific schema because I thought it would cause more confusion than help. In short, I'm creating a very large graph using Gephi, exporting it via a google maps plugin to a .JSON to store in MySQL for faster reference since it's so big. Here is a proof of theory without the database: https://googlemapsexporter.firebaseapp.com/index2.html . I'd give a more specific error, but everything I've used so far seems inappropriate for this project. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I store this information in a MySQL database?

That question leads to answer paralysis. I can think of about a dozen different ways, depending upon how you want to extract data, whether your queries are off-line or online, data volume, server-side vs. embedded business logic, and so on.

Fundamentally, SQL is declarative: you tell it what data you want *out*, and the engine figures out the best way to give it you. So your focus when faced with the blank slate of raw data is to list the questions the data will answer. Here are a few examples:

1. How many edges are shorter than N units? What are they? Order them by length.
2. How many vertices are within N units of each other? What are they? Order them in pairs by edge length.
3. How many vertices are within the minimum-bounding-rectangle [x1,y1,x2,y2]? What are they? How many are connected to another vertex outside the MBR?

Without knowing the kinds of answers you want from the data, it's impossible for anyone -- even you -- to build a solution.

Nonetheless, you may need to explore some avenues more to figure out what those questions are. Here are some possible ways to go about it:

1. Create tables `nodes`, `edges`, and `connections` with a column for each respective property: `weight`, `size`, etc.. Use a command line tool like `jq` to iterate over every "node" and every "edge", inserting into the respective tables. Obviously, make the join using `source` and `target`.
2. Similar to above, but instead of a single column for each attribute, use the MySQL `JSON` type to hold the raw JSON. Use MySQL to query.

Comment: Wow, great post! Thanks for the insight. For now I think I will try to use MySQL to hold the raw JSON, and then move from there as I get more comfortable with how everything works.

Comment: Although, I tried making a table similar to what you said: https://ideone.com/F4FRU8 not sure if I did it right though

Comment: Looks correct, and works for me in MySQL 5.6.23. I suggest you try in a different database environment.

Comment: Thanks for checking that! The table created fine for me too, although inserting values has been a different story entirely. I really would prefer to use some other database environment, but unfortunately I'm stuck with MySQL. Anywho, I'll stop bugging you, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've been in your situation before. What I've learned there is not many "one-size-fits-all" especially for importing XML/JSON data. You might have to create a model class just for ORM to work. Seems a lot of work for a simple importing task.

I would suggest creating your own PHP script for reading JSON, iterating elements and nodes, then finally perform a parameterized query to bind the values into a SQL insert query.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks. I appreciate the help.

Comment: thanks @jmsweb , if all else fails I will try to give your method a try. Thanks a bunch for your insight

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you know any framework but you can use e.g. Symfony framework
there is one Bundle which can help:

http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

With this bundle and library called Doctrine you can deserialize any json (event with relations) to entities classes and save in database
But if you have never worked with any of this it could be hard to implement it

Comment: looks interesting, I've never worked with any of this before. But I'll check it out anyways!